# How to build only main.bundle.js

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

In Angular application, I have a requirement to build a plugin along with the main application.

This plugin is just a wrapper over subset of components from main application and currently I am building it by configuring a second Angular application inside *angular-cli.json*. (Following [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps)).

To output the build, I have to separately build the main application and plugin application. Then I move the plugin app build inside the main app build because this is the deployment structure.

Obviously this doubles the size, although plugin app just has a few lines of code and uses everything from the main application.

I beleive **main.bundle.js** is the file that contains Angular application code.

Is it possible that for the plugin, I only output *main.bundle.js* and *index.html*. And then in the plugin's *index.html* I refer other files form main application e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../inline.f5ed4d8be055cd41a552.bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ng build --watch
```

This will rebuild any changed files (ie only the delta so it's quicker). Generally only your source changes, so effectively main.js gets the rebuild.

I am using this with MVC5/bundling to rebuild my bundles. I still have to refresh the browser after a change, but its better than stop/starting the whole environment!

Comment: With MVC bundling, you are not able to use `ng serve`?